# Observable - Subscribe doesn't receive expected value

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I've created a Service which contains the next methods:

```
public getSomething(): Observable<MyObject> {
    if (this.myObject) {
      return of(this.myObject); #
    } else {
      return this.myService.DoIt().pipe(
        switchMap((result) => {
          if (result) {
            return this.getObject();  !!!!
          } else {          
            const myObject = new MyObject('Something');
            return of(myObject); #
          }
        }),
        catchError((error) => {
          return this.handleError(error);
        })
      );
    }
  }
  private getObject(): Observable<MyObject> {
    const tempresult = this._http.get<MyObject>({
      endpoint: '/something'
    });
    return tempresult.pipe(
      map((result) => {
        this.myObject = MyObject.fromJson(result);
        return this.myObject;
      })
    );
  }
```

In a component, the 'getSomething' method will be called, using:

```
this.someService.getSomething().subscribe((result) => {
      result -> The subscribe never contains the data of the 'return this.getObject();'
    });
```

The lines marked with # are returing the correct data, but the !!!! marked line never returns the value in the subscribe. So apparently I'm doing something wrong, but I can't find a solution. I would expect the value of 'return this.getObject(); ' in certain cases as result in the subscribe.

Could you point me in the right direction? I think the issue is caused by the current structure of having a pipe -> pipe which needs to return the Observable.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem. Are you sure `this.myService.DoIt()` emits `true`?

Comment: While using a breakpoint, the code does hit 'return this.getObject();', but the subscribe doesn't receive the value.

Comment: I guess `this._http.get()` might throw an error that is caught by `catchError` (maybe it supresses the error)? It's hard to give any advice without a reproducible demo.

Answer (score 0):

One reason why the following line:

```
return this.getObject();
```

does not return any data is that the routine getObject() contains a HTTP request and returns an
observable, which requires a subscription before the request can execute on the server and return
an emitted value from the observable.

I would recommend the following:

```
this.getObject().subscribe(res => 
{
    return of(res);
});
```

Comment: no no, this won't work. Returning a value from `subscribe` handler won't do anything.

Comment: I use subscribe() for http requests quite often and it always returns a value. Anyway, it is a suggestion. Perhaps you can refactor the code to use just one level of the pipe() operator.